# UDP communication is lost on linux, are "UDP sockets" managed differentely on linux compared to windows when using C# .NET Core 2.1?

Tags: linux, sockets, ubuntu, .net-core, udp

I have a C# .NET Core 2.1 application that runs fine on windows. A listener task for incoming UDP packets and another thread which sends UDP-packets. The software communicates with an embedded device using a proprietary protocol above UDP which requires "PING-PONG" (ACK) in order to "stay alive".

When running the application on windows I have no problem with the communication. When I run this on Linux Ubuntu (18.04) I sometimes have trouble communicating. Sometimes the communication is lost (packets don't arrive to the application although they are visible in Wireshark) and so on, basically it behaves bad...

The code more or less uses basic stuff from online tutorials for the "back-bone" of UDP communication (listener and so on). Do you have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Well UDP *is* unreliable, packets can get lost *anywhere* along the route, including in your computer. However, if the packet is received by the operating system, but not your program, the chances are that it's a problem with your program.

Comment: I have resending mechanisms and so on, but the behavior seems very sporadic, also I see like a "lag" when starting the communication on linux compared to windows. Are there like any differences when it comes to socket buffers on linux compared to windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a combination of linux socket buffers which I increased to:

```
    net.core.rmem_max=26214400
    net.core.rmem_default=26214400
    net.core.wmem_max=26214400
    net.core.wmem_default=26214400
```

(in /etc/sysctl.conf)

and proprietary protocol specific bugs...